# How do I rotate a geomorph graph?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to rotate the graph obtained by the following lines of code.

```
average.shape <- mshape(croc_gpa_landmarks$coords)
plotRefToTarget(average.shape, PCA$shapes$shapes.comp1$min, links = jaw.links, label=F) #PC1 min
```

The plot is fine, but it is mirrored and rotated 90 degrees clockwise, making the interpretation a bit confusing to external observers.

While flipping the graph is pretty straightforward, rotating it is proving to be a nightmare. I tried to look around for tutoriald, strings of code or packages, but I am unable to solve my seemingly simple issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Currently, your post doesn't provide a lot of details so it's hard to help you. So far, you are the only one that can see the problem because no one except for you can run this code (we don't have access to `croc_gpa_landmarks`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to build a **reproducible example**. Use a dataset that everyone has access to, for example `iris`, or use `dput()` on a sample of your data and paste the output in your post.

Comment: Greetings! As another has noted, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg